# How to store multiple data for different Keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have large data associated with each different keys. I'm planning to store data in this format in php

```
$item = array(
(
        "key" : key-value;
        "features" : array-of-features;
        "small_images" : array-of-small_images;
    ),

    (
        "key" : key-value;
        "features" : array-of-features;
        "small_images" : array-of-small_images;
    ),

    (
        "key" : key-value;
        "features" : array-of-features;
        "small_images" : array-of-small_images;
    )
);
```

Any idea how can i create data structure like this mentioned above and how to access its values in PHP.If there is any other way then do mention that to.

**EDIT :** Note the data here is in array is array-of-features and array-of-small_images is an associative array which contains key same as the main main and value as its value.

Comment: database is a good option

Comment: Use JSON format http://json.org/example.html. You can create a associative array and convert to json using `json_encode()`

Comment: @xXxpRoGrAmmErxXx my basic purpose is to store in an array but issue is that this data is coming in loop which runs around 100 times so using insert query inside loops is not recommended. So i want to collect data in loops in a data structure like $item and then do something like batch insert.

Comment: @Jigar "how can i create data structure like this" means set up for storing data in this structure and the key is unique for all items here.

Comment: yea got that later, so deleted my comment. What @xXxpRoGrAmmErxXx is saying is right. You don't need to query everytime in the loop, just create one big query in the loop and then execute the query outside the loop. You can even decide the chunks of data to be inserted at a time, if the query gets too heavy.

Comment: @Jigar nice idea .Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Associative array is ideal solution if keys are unique:

```
$items['key1']['features'] = array-of-features;
$items['key1']['small_images'] = array-of-small_images;

$items['key2']['features'] = array-of-features;
$items['key2']['small_images'] = array-of-small_images;

...
```

Then, you may loop items with foreach:

```
foreach($items as $key => $item) {
  echo "\n<pre>$key => " . print_r($item, 1) . "</pre>";
}
```